chai.request is not a function when I use .js files
I have this libs installed in my package.json:
{
  "name": "22)-tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.3",
    "chai": "^5.1.1",
    "chai-http": "^5.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^8.0.1",
    "mocha": "^10.7.3",
    "mysql2": "^3.11.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.4"
  }
}

I have an index.js with this logic:
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import exphbs from 'express-handlebars';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import sequelize from './db/connection.js';
import homeRoutes from './routes/homeRoutes.js';
import saveRoutes from './routes/saveRoutes.js';

dotenv.config();

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();

sequelize.sync().then(() => console.log('DB OK!'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs.engine({
  defaultLayout: false,
}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', homeRoutes);
app.use('/', saveRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

sequelize.sync({ force: false }) 
  .then(() => {
    console.log('DB Sync!');
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Started ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error Sync: ', err);
  });

export default app;

Inside test folder, I have a file called view.test.js with this code:
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import app from '../index.js';

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const { expect } = chai;

describe('HTML Test', () => {
    it('Should return correct HTML Content', (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                expect(res.text).to.include('List of names from API');
                done();
            });
    });
});

Unfortunately I am getting the error chai.request is not a function. In my case I am using ES6 in conjunction with Javascript.
I don't plan on using Typescript, and as far as I know, both Chai and Mocha don't work very well with require.
How to solve this problem?

Does this answer your question? https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19480#issuecomment-520688326
